# Shiny app does not reflect changes in update RData file

Tags: r, shiny

I update my RData file on daily basis through a cron job for my shiny apps.
However, shiny apps does not pick updates most of the time and keep showing the old data from old RData file.

Here is the minimum reproducible example. It works fine when ***data_processing.R*** is executed from my desktop. However, when it is done on a Rshiny server, shiny app does not read updated date and time stamp.

**data_processing.R**

```
rm(list=ls())
df <- iris
data_update_date_time <- Sys.time()
save.image("working_dataset.RData", compress = TRUE)
```

**server.R**

```
load("working_dataset.RData")

function(input, output, session) {

  # Combine the selected variables into a new data frame
  selectedData <- reactive({
    df[, c(input$xcol, input$ycol)]
  })

  clusters <- reactive({
    kmeans(selectedData(), input$clusters)
  })

  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
    palette(c("#E41A1C", "#377EB8", "#4DAF4A", "#984EA3",
              "#FF7F00", "#FFFF33", "#A65628", "#F781BF", "#999999"))

    par(mar = c(5.1, 4.1, 0, 1))
    plot(selectedData(),
         col = clusters()$cluster,
         pch = 20, cex = 3)
    points(clusters()$centers, pch = 4, cex = 4, lwd = 4)
  })

  ## Data update date and time stamp
  output$update_date_time <- renderPrint(data_update_date_time)

}
```

**ui.R**

```
pageWithSidebar(
  headerPanel('Iris k-means clustering'),
  sidebarPanel(
    selectInput('xcol', 'X Variable', names(iris)),
    selectInput('ycol', 'Y Variable', names(iris),
                selected=names(iris)[[2]]),
    numericInput('clusters', 'Cluster count', 3,
                 min = 1, max = 9),
    br(),
    h4("Date update date time"),
    textOutput("update_date_time")
  ),
  mainPanel(
    plotOutput('plot1')
  )
)
```

Thanks for taking your time.

Comment: If you put `load("working_dataset.RData")` inside your server-function, the image should get reloaded with every new session. The lifetime of variables outside the server function is pretty much unpredictable AFAIK.

Comment: Thanks for the great suggestion.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### Edit

There is actually a function called `reactiveFileReader` in the `shiny` package that does exactly what you are looking for: Periodically checking if the files "last modified" time or size changed and rereading accordingly. However, this function can only be used in the `server` context, so the file will be read at least once for each user that connects to your app. Options 3 and 4 in my Answer do not have these inefficiencies.

### Original Answer from here on

First and foremost, shiny does not have a way to keep track of filechanges AFAIK. Your implementation reloads the `.RData` file whenever

1. `shiny-server` gets restarted via bash or
2. the global variables get reloaded because the app became idle at some point.

There is no way of telling, when the second condition is met. Therefore, I would advocate using one of the following four options. Sorted from **easy** to **you better know your shiny!**.

### Option 1: Put the load statement in server

Here, the image is reloaded whenever a new user connects with the app. However, this might slow down your app if your `.RData` file is huge. If speed is not an issue, I would pick this solution since it is easy and clean.

```
# server.R
function(input, output, session) {
  load("working_dataset.RData")
  ...
}
```

The data will also be reread whenever a user refreshes the page (<kbd>F5</kbd>)

### Option 2: Restart shiny-server whenever you want to re-import your data

(*Also see @shosacos answer*). This forces the `.Rdata` file to be reloaded.

```
$ sudo systemctl restart shiny-server
```

Again, this might slow-down your production process depending on the complecity of your app. One advantage of this approach is that *you can also use the imported data to build the ui* if you load the data in `global.R`. (I assume you don't given the code you gave).

### Option 3: Import according to "last modified"

The idea here is to *check whether the `.RData` has changed* whenever a user connects to the app. To do this, you will have to use a "global" variable that contains a timestamp of the last imported version. The following code is untested, but should give you an idea on how to implement this feature.

```
# server.R
last_importet_timestamp <- reactiveVal("")

function(input,output,session){
  current_timestamp <- file.info(rdata_path)$mtime 

  if(last_importet_timestamp() != current_timestamp){
    # use parent.frame(2) to make data available in other sessions
    load(rdata_path, envir = parent.fame(2))
    # update last_importet_timestamp
    last_importet_timestamp(current_timestamp) 
  }

  ...
}
```

Speed-wise, this should be more efficient than the first two versions. The data is never imported more than once per timestamp (unless shiny server gets restarted or becomes idle).

### Option 4: Import "reactvely"

Basically, the same as option 3 but the file will be checked for changes every 50ms. Here is a full working example of this approach. Note that the data is not loaded unless a change in "last modified" is detected, so the resulting overhead is not too bad.

```
library(shiny)

globalVars <- reactiveValues()

rdata_path = "working_dataset.RData"

server <- function(input, output, session){
  observe({
    text = input$text_in
    save(text = text, file = rdata_path, compress = TRUE)
  })
  observe({
    invalidateLater(50, session)
    req(file.exists(rdata_path))
    modified <- file.info(rdata_path)$mtime
    imported <- isolate(globalVars$last_imported)
    if(!identical(imported, modified)){
      tmpenv <- new.env()
      load(rdata_path, envir = tmpenv)
      globalVars$workspace <- tmpenv
      globalVars$last_imported <- modified
    }
  })
  output$text_out <- renderText({
    globalVars$workspace$text
  })
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  textInput("text_in", "enter some text to save in Rdata", "default text"),
  textOutput("text_out")
)

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

If you find it inconvenient to use `globalVars$workspace$text`, you can use `with` to access the contents of `globalVars$workspace` directly.

```
  output$text_out <- renderText({
    with(globalVars$workspace, {
      paste(text, "suffix")
    })
  })
```

Comment: Cordial thanks for your super helpful answer... Really appreciate your time!

Answer (score 2):

It works if you restart your shiny server after the new *.RData is processed. I wouldn't put it into the shiny server because then

1) Its variables are not visible to the UI

2) Every user that opens the app needs to wait for RData loading to finish.

Comment: In the example OP gave, the variables are already unacessible in the ui since the load statement is in `server.R`, not in `global.R`. Other than that, I agree that if OP wants to build his UI from the `.RData` image, this approach is best.

Answer (score 2):

The app is cached by shiny server and it does not update the app unless a change is detected in one of .R files associated with your shiny app. A hack is to make a subtle change in your app code (e.g. switch the loading order of libraries) to prompt shiny server to reset the cache and thereby include your updated .RData file.

On linux you can simply execute **touch app.R**

Comment: Changing even in the `server.R` is not getting shiny server to pick the new updated app. It still goes to the old app. I guess the previous app is not getting terminated as I can see the server log is updating even after shutting the app from my browser. Seems the app is still alive.

Comment: This worked for me for a changed CSV data source not being picked up, but I also noticed in the app in question (mine to fix, not mine originally) that data _is_ being loaded outside the server function, so that will be the next thing to check, per other answers here.