# What is the best way to have shiny update at specific times?

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

I want to update a bunch of variables across all users at the same time, every 10 seconds.

Currently, I have the server updating at specific system times. However, the issue with my current invalidation technique is that the invalidation repeatedly updates on the same condition when I only want to update once. Below is an example of my current approach.

Is there a better way to achieve my end goal? Is there a better way to update at specific system times?

### server.R

```
## Load User Profiles 
Participants <- readRDS("Participants.RData")
ReactParts <- reactiveValues()

## Which Times to Update
submit_times <- Sys.time() + c(1:10)

observe({

    invalidateLater(1000)
    stime_test <- round(Sys.time() - submit_times,0) == 0 

    if( any(stime_test) ){
      ## Do a bunch of calculations ...
      ## update reactive variables
      ReactParts$Participants <<- Participants
```

Comment: You can save a timestamp for the last updatetime and use it as a second conditon in your if statement. I used a similar logic in my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46719268/shiny-app-does-not-reflect-changes-in-update-rdata-file/46747407#46747407).

Comment: are those reactive variables shared among users globally?

Comment: They are shared globally. I've edited the code to show exactly what is being updated. @GregordeCillia Thanks for the direction.

Comment: For future reference, `reactivePoll` is useful here.