# Shiny system call with continuous updates

Tags: r, shiny

I have a shiny app that makes a system call starting a second process, in this case a c++ program (for various reasons Rcpp is not an option for this project). The c++ program takes some time to run but gives continuous (as in a couple of times per second) feedback to the terminal.

I can execute the program from the shiny app and retrieve the output of the system call, but it waits until the process is finished.

Now my question is, is there a way to continuously update the text inside the shiny app?

As an example, I have the following shiny app

```
ui <- bootstrapPage(
  verbatimTextOutput("text")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  a <- system("./tmp", intern = T, wait = F)
  output$text <- renderText(paste(a, collapse = "\n"))
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

and the following c++ code (in `tmp.cpp` compiled with `g++ tmp.cpp -o tmp`)

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        printf("i is now %i\n", i); // print the current state
        fflush(stdout);             // force the print
        usleep(1000000);            // sleep for one second
    }
    return 0;
}
```

After waiting the ten seconds, the output gets displayed, instead I want each step to be shown.

Any ideas/solutions to this? Thanks a lot!

Comment: You can save your C++ output as a text file and read that file "reactively". See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46719268/shiny-app-does-not-reflect-changes-in-update-rdata-file/46747407#46747407) (Option 4).

Comment: That looks perfect, if you write a short answer, I will gladly upvote and accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, I advocate for a connection between C++ and shiny via a text file. My answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46719268/shiny-app-does-not-reflect-changes-in-update-rdata-file/46747407#46747407) shows you how to import a file "reactively". The following is adapted from option 4 in the linked answer.

Notice that the process will get started once for each user that connects, so you might want to tweak this code by moving the line `system("./tmp > mytext.txt", intern = F, wait = FALSE)` into `global.R`.

```
ui <- bootstrapPage( 
  verbatimTextOutput("text") 
) 

server <- function(input, output, session) { 

  system("./tmp > mytext.txt", intern = F, wait = FALSE) 

  observe({ 
    ## read the text file once every 50 ms
    invalidateLater(50, session)
    req(file.exists("mytext.txt")) 
    txt <- paste(readLines("mytext.txt"), collapse = "\n") 
    output$text <- renderText(txt) 
  }) 
} 

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```